# Copying over arrays of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, dynamic

I am trying to make a dynamic array of objects in an array Subject that takes in an input file and, depending on how many subjects there are, will continue to create a new array of a new size. Here is what I have been testing. The error I have been getting is a segmentation fault. I do not understand why.

Input file is a subjects.txt that has students and id like this:

English 123456

Dance 123457

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)  
{
    ifstream input;
    input.open("subjects.txt");

    string subject;
    string id;
    int index;
    int size;

    index = 0;
    size = 1;

    Subject *array;
    Subject *temp;

    array = new Subject[size];

    while (fin >> subject) {
        input >> id;

        array[index].set_subject(subject);
        array[index].set_id(id);

        temp = new Subject[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            temp[i].set_subject(array[i].get_subject());
            temp[i].set_id(array[i].get_id());
        }

        size++;
        delete [] array;
        array = temp;
        index++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Typo `fin >> subject` ->`input >> subject`?

Comment: Consider bundling that array up inside its own class and turn it into a poor man's `vector`. This can save you a lot of trouble by separating the array management code from the rest of your logic. As an added bonus, you now have a groovy little class you can use next assignment and the assignments after that until your instructor allows you to use `std::vector`.

Comment: @user4581301 Nevermind I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The array `array` emerges from that loop the same size as when it went in. Then you attempt to write past the end of it, and get a segmentation fault.

Change this:

```
temp = new Subject[size];
```

to this:

```
temp = new Subject[size+1];
```